# Retrieve values from a RESTORE LABELONLY operation

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to retrieve the resulting value of the following query :

```
RESTORE LABELONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\folder\db-backup.bak';
```

After doing some search I tried:

```
string connection = @"data source=.\SQLExpress;initial catalog=DB;persist security info=False;user id=sa;password=12356;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework";
ExecuteSQL(connection , @"RESTORE LABELONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\folder\db-backup.bak'");
```

And, the ExecuteSQL is:

```
private void ExecuteSQL(string ConnString, string sqlText)
    {
        string result = "";
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            using (SqlCommand sqlCom = sqlCon.CreateCommand())
            {
                sqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                sqlCom.CommandText = sqlText;
                sqlCom.CommandTimeout = 0;
                try
                {
                    string str = Convert.ToString(sqlCom.ExecuteScalar());
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    result = e.Message;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

BUT .. the str always empty !!

The result of the query in SQL Server Management Studio is:

[image]

What I want is how can I retrieve the MediaSetID field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186268.aspx) says about the `RESTORE LABELONLY` operations:

> Result Sets
>
> The result set from RESTORE LABELONLY consists of a single row with
>   this information.
>
> MediaName nvarchar(128)   Name of the media.

...

So you have to use [ExecuteReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx) method and process the columns in the returned [reader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx) (or load it to `DataTable` and do the same).

Comment: @Eugebe Podskal Thank you so much for helping

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `ExecuteReader()` instead like below since your said command returning non-scalar value. You probably getting empty string cause the first column value of the `RESTORE` command is `NULL` per your posted SSMS result image

```
sqlCom.ExecuteReader()
```